# Why progress bar is not visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I am trying to fix the progress bar at the bottom, but it is not visible...

```css
.sticky-progress-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="progress sticky-progress-bar">
 
  <div class="progress-bar w-50 progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: because there is no content in it?

Comment: But when I remove `position: fixed;` it is being displayed...

Comment: Aren't all the answers below are same as the accepted one?

Comment: @Akshay I would use `right:0;left:0;` instead of `width:100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a width

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: He said he is trying to fix it but it's not visible, giving it a width will show the progress bar, have you even tried?

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, the issue is due to a lack of width, but I believe you also need an answer of *why* your `<div>` needs a width.

By default a `<div>` takes up the full width of its parent due to its default display of `block`. `position:fixed` essentially knocks the element out of the document flow and no longer respects the width of the parent, and instead relies on its own width value. With no width set, the default is 0, which is why you don't see the progress bar.

Comment: Nice answer too :)

Comment: the default width is not 0 but it's more complex depending on different properties like explained here : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

Answer (score 0):

your progress div has not an content, so that your width is 0, you can set width: 100% and its will be work fine.

```css
.sticky-progress-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -4px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="progress sticky-progress-bar">
 
  <div class="progress-bar w-50 progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add `width:100%` in the *progress* class.

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And your progress will be visible!